# Why is there a difference between Row total and Column total?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171QRNUrVyDndex60tBqktc1d0rLjx0NfvsYfPwBlkEo/edit?usp=sharing)My question is how can I make the same amount of value in line blue and line red? It was supposed to be the same amount.

[image: screenshot]

[blue line =SUM(I7:I194 red line: =SUM(J195:X195))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GBVR.jpg)

Comment: you should upload you sheet instead of a screenshot.

Comment: CAN I UPLOAD THE SHEET HERE?

Comment: I guess not. use dropbox or something. Firefox send can be pretty good in this case I guess.

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & load the sample data so we could visualize and fix the issue, also share both formula with us too!!

Comment: @Rajesh did you see it?

Comment: Divide your data (horizontally, for example), calculate sums and verify. Find a half where miscalculation posessed. Then divide this half again... find a cell (or cells) which causes miscalculation. Try to understand why.

Comment: @justmeinaloneplace98,, I've used your data set & got the expected result  `342,657.25` form both directions  ( total  of column `A` is equals to total of Col `B to P`) since I've copied your data in Range `A1:P187`.

Comment: @justmeinaloneplace98,, make your Google Sheet editable so that I'll update with formula!!

Comment: Try to check the 10.71 value in column X.

Comment: @Rajesh S https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171QRNUrVyDndex60tBqktc1d0rLjx0NfvsYfPwBlkEo/edit?usp=sharing  This is the sheet

Comment: @justmeinaloneplace98,, I've copied data & rewritten formula & got similar value `342.667.95` no difference, and yes Google sheet has two different values!!

Comment: @justmeinaloneplace98,, since  your sheet is still Read only so u unable to rewrite formula ,, better you check my profile ,, get mail ID,, send one test mail,, I'll return sheet to you!!

Comment: Hi I already send it in your email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference is hard to tell without looking at the data or the formulas.

The difference is 10.71, so quite significant.

- Check that the row total formulas do not omit any columns
- check that the column total formulas do not omit any rows
- check formulas for rounding

In the screenshot, all the row totals have 0 decimals, but the total has a 0.24 decimal. Check which row that comes from and you may find that this is the error row, since all other rows total to a round number.

If all that does not help, share the file on an ad-free file sharing service and post a link in your question.

Comment: I cannot upload it here

Comment: @justmeinaloneplace98 Copy your data to Google Sheets and share.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171QRNUrVyDndex60tBqktc1d0rLjx0NfvsYfPwBlkEo/edit?usp=sharing This is the sheet

Answer (score 1):

I see constants instead of formulas in your `I` column and your `191` row. Assuming these values are sums, then there are 3 cells that have wrong values:
 `I124` should be 89.29  instead of 100
 `I88` should be  205.51 instead of 205.50
 `T191` should be 3357.82 instead of 3357.81